# How to get the longitude and latitude from the GPS on WP7?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, gps

I'm writing an app that needs to get the longitude and latitude from the GPS on the phone. I'm saving up money to buy a phone, but for now, I'll have to stick to the emulator. Is there a way I can simulate some fake, random gps settings with the emulator?

A question aside: Is there any Windows Phones I should avoid buying, any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The emulator on its own doesn't provide any "fake GPS" support, but there are a few emulator tricks around to allow you to fake GPS data:

e.g.

- http://phone7.wordpress.com/2010/08/19/gps-sim-update-generic-model-and-dll/ - see http://phone7.wordpress.com/2010/08/02/no-device-no-gps-no-matter-with-code/ for pictures
- http://wp7gps.codeplex.com/
- the official one is http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2011/01/28/windows-phone-gps-emulator.aspx

I've previously used http://wp7gps.codeplex.com/ solution - I chose it before the official one was out as it gives you the same data each time (helped with testing)

Comment: I've just added the official one to the list too!

Answer (score 1):

Above codeplex link have fake.cs file that is not working at all. and other link u folks are provided are expired.

If there is any good solution to **simulate fake gps** or **find current location** on emulator then post any sample App please